# Index rows to prevent misleading data in cell?

Tags: c#, datagridview, header, cell

In a datagridview, I have counters being updated starting from zero via messages being sent in and out. These messages have types, so type A would be incremented if a type A message was sent either in or out. I've allowed user sorting so the user can see which types of messages are being sent or received the least or most. However, since I'm updating the specific cell in the row of the message, once you sort the rows, a different number would be there and thus, another counters' value would be changed instead. For example,

I have types A, B, and C.

A has 4 messages
B has 6 messages,
C has 32 messages.

Let's say Message type C is coming in right now, but the user sorts the columns, and then the order would be

C 32
B 6
A 4.

Since this is the order, my problem is that I'm updating the cell value. So in the datagrid, I'd be updating cell [1, 2]'s value. Which means A would then have a counter of 5, and C would still have a counter of 32, which is not true. I know the message type is C, so is there some way to index the rows so I know exactly which row's cell value to update rather than updating the cell itself? This leads to a pretty large error and rows do not have names, so I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I'm thinking of using the header cell's name and setting the header cell of the rows to A, B, C, and whenever type C comes in, I look for which row the headercell 'C' is in, then navigate to the column and update the cell number.

Any insight is appreciated. Thank you so much!

.NET 3.5 SP1.
-tf.rz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DataGridView is not bound to any [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) you should do so.  That way you can update your the DataGridView's DataSource and the DataGridView takes care of updating the correct cell(s) for you.

If your DataGridView is bound to a DataSource you need to update the DataSource instead of the DataGridView directly.

Comment: that did the trick. I totally forgot about datasources. Appreciate it! Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

You need to search the rows after every Message. The easiest way is iterating

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
```